# Remote desktop connection similar to Windows XP

Tags: remote-desktop, remote

I recently installed Ubuntu on my home PC. How do I connect to my employer's network via remote desktop like I used to do when I ran XP?

Answer (score 2):

[Remmina [image: Install remmina]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/remmina) remote desktop is the pre-installed remote desktop app in Ubuntu.

- Start *Remmina* by typing it in the Dash.
- Select *New Connection*
- Provide a *name* and select the *RDP-Windows Terminal Service*
- Provide all the data you used to use on your XP machine to connect to your employers computer in the basic tab.
- Click *connect*

You can find a step by step guide with screenshots [here](http://www.7tutorials.com/connecting-windows-remote-desktop-ubuntu).

Comment: you are totally right.. I'll edit..

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example `rdesktop` to connect to a remote desktop. Perhaps you have to install this application first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a vnc server to share your desktop. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC. Next you will need a vnc client at the other end, something like Remmina (preinstalled) for ubuntu or RealVNC for windows.